# Tried and failed to push a large file, now I cannot even push a readme

Tags: git, github

I tried and failed to push some large csv files to githib with a message telling me the file was too large.
So, I used `git rm --cached file.csv` to delete them and then tried to push again.
However, the push looks like it is trying to push the same large file that failed like before. I suspect that the large file is still present in some form and I want to remove it from git so that I can just push the code files.

Here's what I see in my terminal after trying the above. It takes a while to push, couple of minutes, when it should presumably take a couple of seconds or less, given there's nothing to push (at least that was my understanding, so I'm confused why it looks and behaves like it did when I initially tried to push the large csv files).

```
git status
 3 files changed, 1814376 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 resources.csv
 delete mode 100644 sample_submission.csv
 delete mode 100644 train.csv
Macs-MacBook:donors_choose macuser$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .DS_Store
    .Rproj.user/
    donors_choose.Rproj
    resources.csv.zip
    sample_submission.csv.zip
    test.csv.zip
    train.csv.zip

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
Macs-MacBook:donors_choose macuser$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 17, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 389.52 MiB | 4.59 MiB/s, done.
Total 17 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

There's a README in the directory and right now all I want to do is add it to my new repo in a "hello world" sense.

The terminal is currently showing the above code ending `Total 17 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)` however the terminal window is unresponsive and nothing shows in the repo on github.

EDIT
After being un responsive for a few minutes the terminal window returned this message:

> To https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git  ! [remote
>   rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed
>   to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers assumes that you fairly recently added that large file into your history, and, that you haven't been able to successfully push any of the commits which contain that large file.

The problem you are facing is that, even after you delete the large file and recommit, the file is still present in your history.  When you go to push, that file will be included, and the hook will reject your push.

Perhaps the simplest fix here would be to do an interactive rebase of your branch:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

This will show you a list of the most recent 5 commits, from oldest to newest.  I assume that the large file was not added more than 5 commits ago.

```
pick u39mask five commits ago
pick 3jd987d four commits ago
pick 9k27dbw three commits ago
pick j1937nd two commits ago
pick wfn83e9 last commit
```

Change `pick` to `edit` for all the commits where the large file might be present:

```
edit u39mask five commits ago
edit 3jd987d four commits ago
edit 9k27dbw three commits ago
edit j1937nd two commits ago
edit wfn83e9 last commit
```

Now save the file and the interactive rebase will begin.  The rebase will pause at each commit you have marked with `edit`.  When that happens, you can manually delete the large file and then type `git rebase --continue` to continue to the next commit.  When all commits have been reapplied, the rebase is over, and hopefully you will have removed all vestiges of the troubling large file.

**Edit:**

If you are new to the Emacs environment in which the rebase commit file will open, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to enter insert mode.  Then change `pick` to whatever you want, e.g. `edit`.  When you are done editing, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> then <kbd>:wq</kbd> to save and close.  Then, the rebase will start.

Comment: ```Macs-MacBook:donors_choose macuser$ git rebase -I HEAD~5
error: unknown switch `I'```. I tried lower case i which gave ```fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD~5```

Comment: @DougFir That is a typo, thanks to my Mac Book, which capitalizes the letter `i`.  Try `git rebase -i HEAD~5`.

Comment: changing ~5 to ~3 got me to the expected view however it's an environment I don't understand. When I try to change pick to edit nothing deletes. Looks like ```pick e138744 New repo for donors competition
pick 73d244b donors choose repo
pick 7723471 donors choose repo

# Rebase a882256..7723471 onto a882256
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
...```

Comment: anything I type in this view doesn't behave as usual/expected!

Comment: @DougFir I cannot train you on Git through a Stack Overflow answer.  I do believe that an interactive rebase is the least painful fix for your problem.  You should realize the mistake you made, and how much work it will be to fix it, so that you don't do it again.

Comment: I'm reading here too: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History. On this link "To do so, change the word ‘pick’ to the word ‘edit’ for each of the commits you want the script to stop after". How?! How can I type over pick to make it become edit?

Comment: Got you now.  Press SHIFT+I to enter edit mode.  Let me update my answer.